# IJSRuntime returns null in Blazor component

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

So I have a blazor component which runs a javascript method inside its OnInitializedAsync method. But it returns null somehow, although the javascript function itself returns something for sure which I checked using debugging. I logged the result of the javascript function and put console.log before and behind the return and behind it didn't show which means it returned something. What it's supposed to return i already debuged using console.log and its the correct result.
This is the code of my blazor component:

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

<div class="summoner-icon" style='background-image: url("@IconPath");'>
    <div class="summoner-level-circle" style="background-color: @_mainColor;">
        <a>@Level</a>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string IconPath { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public long Level { get; set; }
    private string _mainColor;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _mainColor = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>
            ("getProfileIconMainColor", IconPath);
    }
}
```

Besides that, here you can see the javascript function:

```
window.getProfileIconMainColor = function (url) {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = url;
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.onload = function () {
        const colorThief = new ColorThief();
        const mainColor = colorThief.getColor(image);
        return rgbToHex(mainColor[0], mainColor[1], mainColor[2]);
        /*return "rgb(" + colorThief.getColor(image).join(",") + ")";*/
    }
}

const rgbToHex = (r, g, b) => '#' + [r, g, b].map(x => {
    const hex = x.toString(16)
    return hex.length === 1 ? '0' + hex : hex
}).join('');
```

Comment: Does it work if you put the _jsRuntime invoke in OnAfterRender rather than OnInitialized?

Comment: Invoke your Javascript function in OnAfterRender event, this is the event which is fired when html elements are created in page  so this is the right  place to call Javascript functions

Comment: Your function `getProfileIconMainColor` does not return anything. The function you assigned to the `load` event does, but that is not part of the JSInterop call you made.